# Expand and collapse child row on click of a link in the parent row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

Guys i'm a newbie to jQuery. I've to make the child rows in a table to hide and show on click of a link in the parent row. I've tried to use jQuery toggle, but i dont know how to make it work when there are multiple rows.

Here's the table -

```
<table class="table table-striped reportTable">
     <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Product Type</th>
              <th>Product Name</th>
              <th>Face Value</th>
              <th>My Stock</th>
              <th>Ordered Stock</th>
              <th>Sub Account Stock</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          <tr>
               <td><a class="showhr" href="#">SIM</a></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td>574,888</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="aser"> <!--child row-->
               <td></td>
               <td>EPin £5</td>
               <td>£05</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="aser"> <!--child row-->
               <td></td>
               <td>EPin £10</td>
               <td>£15</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td><a class="showhr" href="#">SIM</a></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td>574,888</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="aser"> <!--child row-->
               <td></td>
               <td>EPin £5</td>
               <td>£05</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="aser"> <!--child row-->
               <td></td>
               <td>EPin £10</td>
               <td>£15</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
           </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () { 
        $(".showhr").click(function () {
           $(".aser").toggle("slow", function () {                
           });
        });
    })
</script>
```

I'm not sure if jQuery toggle is a good idea for this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using `closest()` and `nextUntil()` methods and `:has()` pseudo selector like following.

```js
$(".showhr").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil("tr:has(.showhr)").toggle("slow", function() {});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped reportTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Type</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Face Value</th>
            <th>My Stock</th>
            <th>Ordered Stock</th>
            <th>Sub Account Stock</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="showhr" href="#">SIM</a></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>574,888</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="aser">
            <!--child row-->
            <td></td>
            <td>EPin £5</td>
            <td>£05</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="aser">
            <!--child row-->
            <td></td>
            <td>EPin £10</td>
            <td>£15</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="showhr" href="#">SIM</a></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>574,888</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="aser">
            <!--child row-->
            <td></td>
            <td>EPin £5</td>
            <td>£05</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="aser">
            <!--child row-->
            <td></td>
            <td>EPin £10</td>
            <td>£15</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If i want one row to be closed while the other is open, how do we do it?

Comment: Add `$(".aser").hide()` at the very first of `click` event. @SagarRaj